# Splitting Laravel / Lumen routes in multiple files

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

Lumen framework comes with the `routes/web.php` file. Reading about how to split the routes in multiple files I came across Laravel documentation (not Lumen) and there it seems pretty clear.

@see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#basic-routing >>> **The Default Route Files**

It states

> All Laravel routes are defined in your route files, which are located in the routes directory. These files are automatically loaded by the framework. The routes/web.php file defines routes that are for your web interface. ...
>
> Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route group by the RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply it to every route in the file. You may modify the prefix and other route group options by modifying your **RouteServiceProvider class**

**So you can just add other route files and edit the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` class,** this seems pretty straight and clear.

Just that Lumen doesn't have any `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` class

So then what's the best way to define your own route files without mangling the framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply include files in web.php? Or is that too simple ;) I don't have Lumen experience, only a lot of Laravel experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent in Lumen is [located in `/bootstrap/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/0a6b6693fa14d0b51f1fd64d8cc783c224060784/bootstrap/app.php#L96-L111).

You can add routes file entries there appropriately. As you can see, there isn't really a specific API for adding files or anything. So just write the logic as you see fit.

Answer (score 8):

We can do this just like Laravel.

Make `routes` directory in root folder.

Inside routes directory create files, for instance,
like `routes/users.php`, `routes/posts.php`

Add above route files, in `bootstrap/app.php` file

```
// Load The Application Routes
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/users.php'; // mention file names 
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/posts.php';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your routes are located in another folder like `app/Api/V1` and your controller are located in `app/Api/V1/Controllers` then you can use the below code in `bootstrap/app.php`

Folder Structure
For route : `app->Api->V1->routes.php`
For Controller : `app->Api->V1->Controllers`

Code:

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Api\V1\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Api/V1/routes.php';
});
```